# Putting images on random created buttons in Java

Tags: java, image, random

I am trying to create a game in Java. In the game, a player will encounter some obstacles by clicking on buttons. Up until now, those obstacles were defined as integers, and if a button was clicked, numbers that represented these objects appeared. I would like to change those numbers into images, but I can't change the count[random1][random2] from int to string. Do you have any suggestions? (I will only add the tree obstacle here and its relevant code).

```
public class Tiles implements ActionListener {
    final static int TREES = 10;
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Game");
    JButton[] [] buttons = new JButton[5][5];
    static int [] [] counts = new int [5] [5];
    Panel grid = new Panel();

    public Tiles() {

        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        makeGrid();

        frame.add(grid,  BorderLayout.CENTER);
        grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
        for (int row = 0; row < buttons.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < buttons[0].length; col++) {
                buttons [row][col] = new JButton();
                buttons [row][col].addActionListener(this);
                grid.add(buttons[row] [col]);
                buttons[row][col].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }

        }



        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void makeGrid() {


        int numTrees = 2;

        Random random = new Random();


        int i = 0;
        while (i < numTrees)  {
            int random1 = random.nextInt(5);
            int random2 = random.nextInt(5);
            if( counts [random1] [random2] == 0) {
                counts[random1] [random2] = TREES;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the type of your `count` variable from `int[][]` to `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>>` (or use the `Table` class from Guava : https://www.baeldung.com/guava-table).
You could then retrieve the `String` representing the image at the position `(i,j)`with `count.get(i).get(j)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am trying to use HashMap (since I am just a beginner, I have never used it before). I am sorry for my beginner question, nevertheless I have to make this game for an assignment.
How would my first counts look like then, because 
`Map <Integer, Map <Integer, String>> counts = new HashMap <5, Map < 5, null>>();`
clearly doesn't work, but that is obviously my bad. In the meantime I will keep searching of course.

Comment: No problem!
You would have to do `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> counts = new HashMap<>();` and then for `i` from `0` to `4` : `map.put(i, new HashMap<>());`.
Then you can fill your map with `map.get(i).put(j, imageString)`.
But to associate a `String` to a `JButton`, it would probably be simpler to use a `Map<JButton, String>`... :)
The best solution in my opinion would be to a create a new class extending `JButton`, and add a `String` property to it.